# how to change foreground color of textblock which is under listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

i have a list box and text block in list-box .I want to change foreground color of text-block when user tap text-block , only tapped text-block should change color for example if i tap another text-block in list previous one should have original color

```
<ListBox Name="URLListBox"  Grid.Row="2"  >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,10" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="surename" Tag="{Binding b1Tag}" FontFamily="Consolas"  FontSize="25" Text="{Binding text}" Tap="surename_Click_1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="60,0,0,0"/>
        <CheckBox IsEnabled="False" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="DarkGreen"  Background="DarkGreen"  Grid.Column="0" x:Name="checkbox" IsChecked="{Binding file}"   ></CheckBox>

      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: you can set a Converter for your tap value and in that you can set default foreground and other foreground

Comment: So you could have a tap event and within that change the textblock foreground property like this 
    textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your window class can look like:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (var g in listBox.Items)
        {
            if (g is Grid)
            {
                foreach (var c in (g as Grid).Children)
                {
                    if (c is TextBlock)
                        (c as TextBlock).MouseDown += TextBlock_Click;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void TextBlock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentSelected != null)
            CurrentSelected.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black); // here you can set foreground default color

        (CurrentSelected = (sender as TextBlock)).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); // here you can set foreground after change
    }

    private TextBlock CurrentSelected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And you have to chnage name of your list box. Simply add:

```
x:Name="listBox"
```

to your list box declaration in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to extend your item class by an additional property (as you are already using binding):

```
// in your item class
private SolidColorBrush frontBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
public SolidColorBrush FrontBrush 
{ 
   get { return frontBrush; }
   set { frontBrush = value; RaiseProperty("FrontBrush"); }
}
```

Then you just set another binding in your TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="surename" Foreground="{Binding FrontBrush}" Tag="{Binding b1Tag}" FontFamily="Consolas"  FontSize="25" Text="{Binding text}" Tap="surename_Click_1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="60,0,0,0" />
```

Then you can simply change colors of your items in a collection (upon click, tap, whenever you want):

```
collection[2].FrontBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```